# transpose column to row

Tags: unix, awk, transpose

I have tried transpose the file below using awk

```
 n   counts
 1  -0.1520
 1  0.0043
 1  -0.4903
 10 0.0316
 10 -0.4076
 10 -0.1175
 200 0.2720
 200 -0.2007
 200 0.0559
```

I need a output like that

```
1   -0.1520 0.0043 -0.4903
10   0.0316 -0.4076 -0.1175
200  0.2720 -0.2007 0.0559
```

I tried but didn´t work

```
awk 'NR==1{print} NR>1{a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2}END{for (i in a){print i " " a[i]}}'
```

Thank you

Comment: what is error you are facing?

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Is the output not sorted? Is the spacing not exactly as requested?

Comment: I modified the separated field for , and I tried awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}  NR>1{a[$1]=a[$1]","$2}END{for (i in a){print i "," a[i]}}' file > outfile.txt and din´t work, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its working. try below

```
awk 'NR==1{print} NR>1{a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2}END{for (i in a){print i " " a[i]}}' file | tac
```

or you can use sort

```
 awk 'NR==1{print} NR>1{a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2}END{for (i in a){print i " " a[i]}}' file | sort -k1 -n
```

Comment: note:   you cannot guarantee the output order of the `for (i in a){print i " " a[i]}`

Answer (score 0):

mmm awk.

```
$ cat bar.awk 
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{getline}
$1 != n {if(row)print row; n=$1; row = $0}
$1 == n {row = row FS $2}
END{ print row }

$ ./bar.awk foo
1  -0.1520 -0.1520 0.0043 -0.4903
10 0.0316 0.0316 -0.4076 -0.1175
200 0.2720 0.2720 -0.2007 0.0559
```

the getline eats the header
the `$1 != n` will notice when the first column changes
`n` will be `0` to begin with so if the first column (& second row) is also zero there will be a problem and you will have to initialize `n` to something else
when the first column changes it is time to print the previous row and begin collecting the next row,
(if the row is empty, as it is initially, don't print it)

when the first column is the same as the previous row,
just append the second value to your row.

finally print the last row.

the `FS` is whatever the current field separator is.

Comment: Thank you! I figured out using dos2unix.